# How to fetch HTTP response body with lua?

Tags: apache, http, lua

I need to parse retreived text from HTTP GET request. I am using Lua on NodeMCU and I am not very familiar with it.

I am using script to fetch response and to split it one row at a time using this script

```
local nStart, nEnd = string.find(c, "\n\n")
if (nEnde == nil) then
    nStart, nEnd = string.find(c, "\r\n\r\n")
end
c = string.sub(c,nEnd+1)
print("length: "..string.len(c))
data = mysplit(c, "\n") -- fill the field with filenames
```

HTTP GET request looks like this

```
GET /lua/node.php?id=4022029&list HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua;)
```

When I print HTTP response, it looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 01:05:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=23p8rtds43pd1662ncm5cjhrl3; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

When I type mydomain.com/lua/node.php?id=4022029&list, I get a list of files as a text one bellow other, but this script is not fetching anything. It looks like there is no body. What am I missing here?

Update,

My script is working when fetching data from HTTP which is not encoding data chunked, but I am not able to fetch it from chunked encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

The server you are connecting to is using [chunked encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which means the header should be followed by one or more chunks that consist of chunk length and the content. It looks like either you haven't finished reading the content or the library you are using doesn't handle the chunked content for some reason.

Comment: I managed to get it working on localhost where HTTP is not encoded chunked. I can't change the encoding on that server, so it will remain chunked. I need to figure it out how to parse that data.